# Выражение "съехать с катушек"

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, с каких катушек съезжают, когда сходят с ума?

Comment: Мне 65, но еще в школе было знакомо это выражение — довольно распространенное. Это я к тому, что колеса глотал и стал очень умным.

Comment: У Достоевского в "Бесах" есть выражение "съехать на санках", в том же смысле.

Comment: Нет, там другое выражение и в другом смысле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сети есть несколько версий, все неубедительные. Тем не менее можно сделать некоторые выводы.

Катушка - это совсем не то, на что нитки мотают. Это то, на чем катятся или катаются.
Железнодорожные катки, например, т.е. блок из нескольких колесных пар. Их, катки, вроде, раньше и называли катушками. Кто не знает конструкцию ж/д вагона наверное удивится, узнав, что катки существуют так сказать отдельно от вагона, это сменная деталь. А потому теоретически она может отделиться -  и вагон с этих катушек сойдет. Или съедет. Тут все правильно и логично, только не очень верится, что подобный редчайший случай мог лечь в основу столь распространенного выражения.
Еще в сети как источник называется ледяная горка - тоже катушка, с которой съезжают и проч.

Все реальные катушки, включая катушки индуктивности и катушки-шпульки для швейных машин, порождают совсем уж фантастические версии типа "нитка сошла с катушки". Как такое может быть - не представляю. Нитка может порваться, но "сойти"? Разве что при ***намотке*** оной катушки - да и то это ж надо умудриться, чтобы нитка перескочила через боковые ограничители и стала наматываться **мимо** катушки - на крутящий вал, видимо...

Comment: Мне вспомнились бобины старых магнитофонов и кинопроекторов, с них плёнка слетала нередко. Правда не уверен, что их катушками называли и не помню, какой при этом эффект.

Comment: Называли катушками — это точно

Comment: Версия  бегемотуса  о  железнодорожном  происхождении  этой  идиоимы  очень  убедительна.  Думаю, что  не  обязательно  это  явление  должно  быть  частым.  Достаточно  и  просто  возможности  такого  события.  Хотя  не  так  давно  на  ВСЖД  было  несколько  аварий  из-за  неисправности  колёсной  пары  -  может  это  похожий  случай ?

Comment: >Версия бегемотуса о железнодорожном происхождении этой идиоимы очень убедительна  
  
А мне как раз не очень нравится. Помнится, где-то участвовал в обсуждениях (как и в обсуждениях едва ли не всех известных идиом), но редкость события стала непреодолимой преградой.   
//----
В кинопроекторах пленка просто рвалась. Техника просто выключалась, а киномеханик занимался клеением. Если не ошибаюсь, для этого использовалась грушевая эссенция. На магнитофонах лента запутывалась, зажевывалась - и её тоже приходилось клеить. Но уже со значительно бОльшими потерями.

Answer (score 4):

У Даля в словаре КАТОК м. отрубок бревна, подкладываемый под тяжести, для перекатывания их; такая же скалка, подделываемая на оси, вместо колес, медведка; костр. ряз. простая скалка, на которой катают белье вальком; каток подкладывают и под ухват, при выемке из печи тяжелых корчаг или чугунов; | станок, для катки белья: по скалкам, которые служат катками, ходит ящик с каменьями... и т.д.
     КАТУШКА, видимо, от слова КАТОК. Получается, что это нечто необходимое для перекатывания какого-то груза. Если он, груз, съедет с катушек/с катка, то это обернется большими проблемами,  трудностями, травмами и прочее. Поэтому процесс "перекатки" требовал точности, умения, опыта, ума.

Я вспомнила еще, как раньше ладьи посуху с помощью подкладываемых бревен перекатывали. Если бревно не так положить, то все плавсредство может раздавить окружающих и само развалиться. Думаю, что в этом процессе участвовали самые-самые. Неопытных и не отличающихся умом не брали. Неудачи в столь сложном деле были сродни сумасшествию.

Comment: Тоже  подойдёт.  Каток, как  и  катушка,  слова  многозначные. Интересно  время  появления  идиомы  -  не  смотрели ?

Comment: В НацКорпусе первое упоминание выражения датировано 1988 или 89. Сомнительно столь древнее происхождение как в ответе, иначе хотя бы тот же Даль зафиксировал бы.

Comment: Не знаю, что там в Нацкорпусе и почему 1988 г. - это древнее. Я его помню, сколько себя.

Comment: Неужели  раньше  в  печать  не  попало ?  Ну,  значит,  это  не  про  те  суда,  которые  на  катках  переволакивали.

Answer (score 1):

Правильных ответов нет ни у кого. Не правы все.
Выражение *съехать с катушек* действительно появилось и широко пошло в народ в 1988-89 годах. Но к поездам и кораблям оно не имеет ровным счётом никакого отношения.
Я помню в своей молодости, когда ещё училась в школе, а было это как раз в до 1989 года, у молодёжи вошло в моду "глотать колёса", т.е. употреблять медицинские препараты с наркотическими свойствами не в лечебных целях, а для получения кайфа. Так вот, глядя порой на неадекватное поведение кого-нибудь из своих сверстников, мы и говорили: "Ты что, с катушек съехал?" Буквально имея ввиду то, что человек сбрендил от колёс (катушек).
Всем привет. Не пью, не курю, не нюхаю и колёс без рецепта не глотаю, потому и на память не жалуюсь. Чего и всем желаю.

Answer (score 1):

И решила я провести "съезжательно-катушечное" расследование...

• Большой словарь русских поговорок дает только три глагола, связанных с катушками:
[сорваться (сойти, съехать) с катушек](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/24878/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
*Прост. Шутл.* Лишиться рассудка, сойти с ума.

На самом деле употребляются еще: *слететь, полететь, послетать, поехать, спрыгнуть, соскочить, сорваться, скатиться, свалиться.*

• У Даля в статье ["катать"](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) о катушке вот только это:
*сиб.* ледяная горка, горушка, катище; || каталка, детская повозочка, игрушка на колесах.

• О [катушке](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/assets/uploads/slovar-russkih-narodnyh-govorov/Slovar_govora-13.pdf) в словаре русских народных говоров (стр. 135):
катание с гор;
ледяная или снежная горка для катанья;
о покатой, наклонной поверхности;
доска с сиденьем, политая водой и обмороженная, на которой катаются с горы, ледянка;
высокие сани, на которых крестьяне в масленицу катаются с гор, стоя и держась за руки;
две обструганные гладкие жерди, скрепленные вместе, облитые водой и замороженные, используемые для катания по двое стоя;
*мн.* ноги; под катушку. Сплошь, дочиста. *Выбило рожь под катушку.* **С катушек долой.** О падении (человека), 1900.

• Употребление (из Нацкорпуса):

*Когда я подрос, мне нравилось **кататься** в масленицу **с катушек**, то есть с небольших гор, сделанных из снега и обливаемых водой* (Ф. М. Решетников. Между людьми **(1864**));
*Сестричка милосердия ― бяк, **с катушек долой**, ― мертвая падаль* (М. М. Зощенко. Великосветская история (**1921**));
*Я, девка, с тобой не то что до мировой революции не дотяну, а вовсе могу **с катушек долой*** (М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (**1932**));
*Он смеялся от души над ее тревогой и уверял старушку, что он еще не совсем **«сошел с катушек»*** (Н. А. Островский. Как закалялась сталь (**1930—1934**));
*Ложился бы скорей, пока **с катушек не свалился**!» ― подумал ординарец, но вслух ничего не сказал, а только повернулся спиной, крякнув, снял с гвоздя пилотку и пошел узнавать* (Константин Симонов. Живые и мертвые (**1955–1959**));
*И он лишь негодующим, прерывающимся шепотом спросил: — Ты что? Того, **с катушек съехал?*** (Петр Проскурин. В старых ракитах (**1983**)).

• Мне кажется, что вероятны такие рассуждения: всё, что относится к катанию на ледяных горках или санях (катушках), связано с большими скоростями и риском падения. Самая опасная — травма головы, поэтому о человеке, который соскочил с катушек (не удержался на ногах, кубарем покатился), и можно сказать, что он потерял голову или с мозгами не дружит.
Возможно, что первоначальным было выражение *с катушек долой*.

Answer (score 0):

в английском есть похожее выражение:

off your rocker = сойти с ума, съехать с катушек.

rocker - это кресло-качалка, от гл. to rock - качать (родств. нем. rücken - дергать).

Есть два варианта происхождения этого выражения:

1. упасть с кресла-качалки, и как результат - ударится головой и свихнуться.
2. ROCKER, или TROLLEY - это еще роликовый токосниматель у трамвая. Если он off - трамвай не едет:

"since both ‘off one’s trolley’ and ‘off one’s rocker’ became popular about the same time streetcars were installed in major American cities, and since ROCKER, like TROLLEY, also means the wheel or runner that makes contact with an overhead electricity supply, it is more likely that the ROCKER of the expression carries this later meaning."

Русское "съехать с катушек" возможно также имеет отношение к поездам или трамваям.

Может быть калька с английского. А может и независимо от английского возникло.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, неправильно не привести еще одну идею. Когда-то в моем детстве бабушка словом «катушка» называла замерзшие небольшие лужи, либо, когда этому способствовали погодные условия, раскатанные подростками узкие, длинные дорожки на тротуарах. Когда созданная ногами "катушка" появлялась, она сначала была небольшой, но с каждым днем становилась длиннее. И в любом случае, в какой-то момент она заканчивалась. Выражение "съехать с катушек" может означать что когда у человека мысли соответствуют тому, что есть на самом деле, то эти мысли очень быстрые, когда не соответствуют - то такие мысли не двигаются, по аналогии как будто человек сначала катился, а потом катушка закончилась, и он остановился.